# Multiple Section Hide & Show with HTML & CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have html button that show/hide the inner sections (Not main section) of my page, I have main section inside main section I five inner sections the details of problem and goals are mentioned in detail with code in below.

**1. Details about my goal**

I want to achieve the hide/show event on the same (single button) without changing its label when user click the button all inner sections should be hidden on the page and again when the user click same button it should show all sections including the one have html button.

**2. Expected and actual results**

Expected results is same as my goal above and actual result in my code is not giving the idea to put the all 5 section to hide.

3. What I have tried so far

```js
document.getElementById("Ayat-3").classList.add("hide-section");
document.getElementById("Ayat-4").classList.add("hide-section");
document.getElementById("Ayat-5").classList.add("hide-section");
document.getElementById("Ayat-6").classList.add("hide-section");
document.getElementById("Ayat-7").classList.add("hide-section");

function toggleHide() {
  var section = document.querySelectorAll('.hide-section');
  section.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('d-none'));
}
```

```css
#button {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 5px;
  border-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 150px;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

.d-none {
  .display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleHide()">Hide/Show Sections</button>
```

**4. Errors that I am facing**

In the above code there is error to hide all mentioned five sections and click on first time its hiding only three sections and same when click second time the different three sections being hidden, i want to hide all five and show up all on second click.

Comment: Script seems to do what is seems to be designed to do. What is your experience? Your description does not match anything we see in the snippet

Comment: Also please use lowercase for HTML tags instead of the mess of uppercase and mixed case you have now

Comment: I have resolved the button customization, the only thing i need is how to add multiple elements to one function with show/hide option.

Comment: I want to have one button only, for your information i have 286 inner sections and the button itself in 1 inner section, what i am trying to do is when user click the button, Then only one inner section should be visible which is the same section where the button is placed all remaining 285 inner sections should be hidden, and upon toggle or click again the same button it should show all sections i mean all 286 inner sections including the one have button.

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete. Please revise the snippet demo so it doesn't error. Also, you have an extra dot in your CSS (`.display`).

Answer (score 0):

To hide multiple elements with a single button click you can use the `querySelectorAll` in combination with the `forEach` command. Then you give all the elements you want to be effected by the script the same class:

```js
function toggleHide() {
  var section = document.querySelectorAll('.hide-section');
  
  section.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('d-none'));
}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>Section will not hide</section>
<section class="hide-section">Section will hide</section>
<section class="hide-section">Section will hide</section>
<section class="hide-section">Section will hide</section>
<section class="hide-section">Section will hide</section>
<button onclick="toggleHide()">Hide/Show Sections</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have seen similar examples on web but i am little confused over where to put my section ID ? let say i have (Ayat-1,Ayat-2,Ayat-3,Ayat-4) four sections on my page and I need to show only Ayat-1 and rest to hide and same appear all once click again. how to add all these section to one class and hide that class on first click and show up again on second click it is too confusing. i am not that much great in coding. if you can modify the code show some example that will be great.

Comment: What prevents you do add a class? Elements can have an id and class at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code, I expected some help from the experts here to identify the errors but anyways its done now.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<button id="Mybutton" onclick='hideSections()'>[1:2]</button>



<style>
#Mybutton  {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 1px;
    
}

#Mybutton:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    
}

    
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.hideWithOpacity {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.section {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  max-width: 150px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

</style>


<section id="Ayat-1"></section>
<section id="Ayat-2"></section>
<section id="Ayat-3"></section>
<section id="Ayat-4"></section>
<section id="Ayat-5"></section>
<section id="Ayat-6"></section>
<section id="Ayat-7"></section>


<script>
    
    function hideSections() {
  const otherSections = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=Ayat-]:not(#Ayat-2)')
  
  otherSections.forEach((section) => section.classList.toggle('hide'))
}

</script>

</html>
```